# How to copy modified files to several servers using ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant

This script works good for the first server (server1), but it doesn't work for the second pass (server2) as at that point all 'modified' files are already flagged by the first pass.

```
<macrodef name="copythings">
<attribute name="todir"/>
<sequential>
    <scp todir="@{todir}" trust="true">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <modified/>
            <include name="cgi-bin/Application/" />
            <exclude name="**/*.log" />
        </fileset>
    </scp>
</sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="deploy">
 <copythings todir="server1"/>
 <copythings todir="server2"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest copying the files from the fileset to a temporary folder first.
And copy to the server from that directory.

1. copy required files to a tempory folder
2. run the targets and use the temporay folder as base/filset for scp
3. delete the temporary folder